# Dates (and next dates) assigned to an Array seems not working

Tags: google-apps-script

this is totally new for me,
if I assign a date to a array record, seems ok, but if I'm assigning the next day to the next record, the system is changing also the first :O :O :O
and so on...

I can't post images, but just try to debug...

```
function myFunction() {

  var test=[];
  var startDate  = new Date(2014,11, 01);  //01 dic 2014
  var nextDate   = startDate ;

  for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
    test.push(nextDate); 
    nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate()+1);
  }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you formulate and communicate a clear and singular question. And perhaps apply some formatting or punctuation to separate the question itself from the supporting information.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the same date object all the time.
Try like below :

```
function myFunction() {
  var test=[];
  var startDate  = new Date(2014,11, 01);  //01 dic 2014
  var nextDate   = startDate ; 
  for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
    var newDate = new Date(nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate()+1));
    test.push(newDate); 
  }
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(test));
}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT :**

To make things more clear and to show the the `nextDate` variable is still the same all along the script execution , here is an example that shows what happens in your original code. I logged the values of `nextDate` in the loop then logged the resulting array. You can indeed see that all values are identical in the array while they change in the loop (and values in the array are the last value in the loop).

Now let's change `nextDate` again and re-check the array, all the values are changed again, that's actually because we have a one and only object.

bad code below :

```
function myFunction2() {
  var test=[];
  var startDate  = new Date(2014,11, 01);  //01 dic 2014
  var nextDate   = startDate ;
  for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
    test.push(nextDate); 
    Logger.log(nextDate);
    nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate()+1);
  }
  Logger.log(test);
  nextDate.setDate(0);
  Logger.log(test);
}
```

result in logger :

[image]

Comment: yes thankyou I resolved with

  var newDate = new Date(nextDate.setDate(nextDate.getDate()+1));
  test.push(newDate);

but I was thinking was a little bit strange that the value in the array, already assigned, is changed